# easymock - matcher and multiple calls

Tags: java, junit, easymock

Below is a test I have knocked up that uses its own matcher. I know in this case I could use a standard matcher but in my real code I need a more complicated one.

The test passes - tick VG.
The issue is that there appears to be an extra call to `IArgumentMatcher.matches()` method that returns false, and yet the test passes.

The output I get is:

```
30-09-2009 16:12:23 [main] ERROR - MATCH - expected[aa], actual[aa]
30-09-2009 16:12:23 [main] ERROR - MISMATCH - expected[aa], actual[bb]
30-09-2009 16:12:23 [main] ERROR - MATCH - expected[bb], actual[bb]
```

So the question is why am I getting the MISMATCH line,
and have I done something incorrectly?

The test code is:

```
package uk.co.foo;

import static org.easymock.EasyMock.createMock;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.replay;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.reset;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.verify;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.easymock.IArgumentMatcher;

/**
 *
 */
public class BillTest extends TestCase { 

  private static Logger mLogger = Logger.getLogger(BillTest.class);

  private BillInterface mMockBill;

  public void testTwoCalls() throws Exception {
    BillsTestClass sut = new BillsTestClass();
    sut.setDao(mMockBill);

    expect(mMockBill.method1(eqBillMatcher("aa"))).andReturn("");
    expect(mMockBill.method1(eqBillMatcher("bb"))).andReturn("");
    replay(mMockBill);

    //test method
    sut.doSomething("aa");
    sut.doSomething("bb");

    verify(mMockBill);
  }

  public String eqBillMatcher(String aIn) {
    EasyMock.reportMatcher(new BillMatcher(aIn));
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    mMockBill = createMock(BillInterface.class);
  }


  @Override
  protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
    reset(mMockBill);
  }

  public class BillsTestClass {
    private BillInterface mDao;
    public void setDao(BillInterface aDao) {
      mDao = aDao;
    }

    public void doSomething(String aValue) {
      mDao.method1(aValue);
    }
  }

  public interface BillInterface {
    String method1(String aValue);
  }

  public class BillMatcher implements IArgumentMatcher {
    private String mExpected;

    public BillMatcher(String aExpected) {
      mExpected = aExpected;
    }

    /**
    * @see org.easymock.IArgumentMatcher#matches(java.lang.Object)
    *  {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public boolean matches(Object aActual) {
     if (aActual.equals(mExpected)) {
       mLogger.error("MATCH - expected[" + mExpected + "], actual[" + aActual + "]");
       return true;
     }
     mLogger.error("MISMATCH - expected[" + mExpected + "], actual[" + aActual + "]");
     return false;
   }

   /**
    * @see org.easymock.IArgumentMatcher#appendTo(java.lang.StringBuffer)
    *  {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public void appendTo(StringBuffer aBuffer) {
     aBuffer.append("boo(");
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick play and it looks like you do not define order just that something should be expected. Each time you make a call to the mock it runs through every expectation in order until it finds one that matches and has not been called before.

So with:

```
expect(mMockBill.method1(eqBillMatcher("aa"))).andReturn("");
expect(mMockBill.method1(eqBillMatcher("aa"))).andReturn("");
expect(mMockBill.method1(eqBillMatcher("cc"))).andReturn("");

sut.doSomething("aa");
```

> MATCH - expected[aa], actual[aa]

Just as you would expect. First match hits.

```
sut.doSomething("cc");
```

> MISMATCH - expected[aa], actual[cc] 
>   MISMATCH - expected[aa], actual[cc]
>   MATCH - expected[cc], actual[cc]

Each one in order (including ones that have already passed) until it finds a hit.

```
sut.doSomething("aa");
```

> MATCH - expected[aa], actual[aa] 
>   MATCH - expected[aa], actual[aa]

Each in order until it finds a hit that has not been called before.

This would enable it to provide the error messages on the lines of "unexpected method call, expected 1, actual 1 (**+1**).

--

Code for comment -

```
private boolean used = false;

<snip/>

public boolean matches(Object aActual) {
   if (used) {
     return false;
   }
   used = true;
```

Comment: I have changed it to use createStrictMock() as I do want to define the order but I was not expecting to get these MISMATCH lines. 

The objects I am comparing are quite complex so that is why I have the logger lines in the Matcher. It is annoying that I see these even when the test passes.

Comment: sorry to be clearer - I only want to see my message in the event of a test failure. Any idea if that is possible ?

Comment: Looking at the way it is implemented (org.easymock.internal.ExpectedInvocation.matches) - No I don't believe you can. You could make BillMatcher smarter (say always return false after it has returned true) but this might confuse EasyMock. (see updated message)